Why does a relatively positioned element share stacking context with sticky (or fixed) preceding element?
codepen
There's a pretty length MDN page describing stacking context, which contains rules for creating a new stacking context. Of note is:


Element with a position value absolute or relative and z-index value other than auto.
Element with a position value fixed or sticky (sticky for all mobile browsers, but not older desktop browsers).


So in the attached codepen, you can see the 'footer' overlap the sticky green box as you scroll down. This only happens when the footer has position: relative; removing that style results in the footer rendering behind the sticky green box. But why? Nothing in the MDN page about stacking context or z-index seems to suggest this element should be creating a new stacking context, much less share a context with its preceding sticky neighbor. Note the question is the same if the green box is 'fixed' as well, so it's not sticky specific.

it's not related to "stacking context" but "painting order"
